# Ruby extract string via regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I have these strings:

```
'da_report/GY4LFDN6/2017_11/view_mission_join_player_count2017_11/index.html'
'da_report/GY4LFDN6/2017_11/activily_time2017_11/index.html'
```

From these two strings, I want to extract these two file names:

```
'2017_11/view_mission_join_player_count2017_11'
'2017_11/activily_time2017_11'
```

I wrote some regular expressions, but they seem wrong.

```
str = 'da_report/GY4LFDN6/2017_11/view_mission_join_player_count2017_11/index.html'
str[/([^\/index.html]+)/, 1] # => "a_r"
```

Comment: Does the string always start with `da_report/GY4LFDN6/`?

Comment: What are the rules?

Comment: yes, it always start with `da_report/GY4LFDN6/`

Comment: @CodaChang Even so, it doesn't mean that it would be good practice to hard code these values, unless you only want to target these types of paths in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression is an overkill here, and i prone to errors.

```
input = [
  "da_report/GY4LFDN6/" \
  "2017_11/view_mission_join_player_count2017_11" \
  "/index.html",
  "da_report/GY4LFDN6/" \
  "2017_11/activily_time2017_11" \
  "/index.html"
]  

input.map { |str| str.split('/')[2..3].join('/') }
#⇒ [
#   [0] "2017_11/view_mission_join_player_count2017_11",
#   [1] "2017_11/activily_time2017_11"
# ]
```

or, more elegant:

```
input.map { |str| str.split('/').grep(/2017_/).join('/') }
```

Comment: Oh, I know this way, and it's a great answer. But I just want to try the regex way.

Comment: `str[%r|(?<=\Ada_report/GY4LFDN6/)\w+/\w+|]` (“I just want to use a regexp“ sounds a bit silly to me; regexp is _not_ a way to go here.)

Comment: Thanks, I will change my way to achieve that.

Comment: @mudasobwa I disagree with your notion of using regex here.  If the OP wanted to filter paths using names, then a string join approach would not be workable.  Regex is not prone to error if the person using it knows regex.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if that was a different task, the different ways to solve it would probably be better. Also, I never said “regexp is prone to errors,” I said “here it’s prone to error.” Also, it’s noticeably slower.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/(?<=GY4LFDN6\/)(.*)(?=\/index.html)/`

```
str = 'da_report/GY4LFDN6/2017_11/view_mission_join_player_count2017_11/index.html'
str[/(?<=GY4LFDN6\/)(.*)(?=\/index.html)/]
 => "2017_11/view_mission_join_player_count2017_11"
```

live demo:  http://rubular.com/r/Ued6UOXWDf

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that you want to capture beginning with the third component of the path, up to and including the last component of the path before the filename.  If so, then we can use the following regex pattern:

```
(?:[^/]*/){2}(.*)/.*
```

The quantity in parentheses is the capture group, i.e. what you want to extract from the entire path.

```
str = 'da_report/GY4LFDN6/2017_11/view_mission_join_player_count2017_11/index.html'
puts str[/(?:[^\/]*\/){2}(.*)\/.*/, 1]
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the values at the end of the string like in the format `string/string` followed by `/filename.extension`, you could use a positive lookahead for a file name.

[`\w+\/\w+(?=\/\w+\.\w+$)`](http://rubular.com/r/J1Gz2eyTq6)

[Demo](http://rextester.com/LKPRV86878)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your examples, you may be able to use a very simple regex.

```
def extract(str)
  str[/\d{4}_\d{2}.+\d{4}_\d{2}/]
end

extract 'da_report/GY4LFDN6/2017_11/view_mission_join_player_count2017_11/index.html'
  #=> "2017_11/view_mission_join_player_count2017_11"
extract 'da_report/GY4LFDN6/2017_11/activily_time2017_11/index.html'
  #=> "2017_11/activily_time2017_11"
```